# Don't worry. It couldn't ever happen

Tags: sentence-meaning, modal-verbs

What does the following sentence mean?

> Don't worry. It couldn't ever happen.

Does **could** refer to present/future or past?

Can we use **ever** in the negative sentences?

---

Does it mean :

1. It cannot happen. (It cannot be true.)
2. It will definitely not happen.
3. It has never happened before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Never is short for **not ever**. Ever could be used in both positive and negative sentences as in "Don't you *ever* tell me a lie again".
2. It means I am sure (confident) that it won't happen. However, I would say "It could never happen" rather than "It couldn't ever happen" as using *never* is more idiomatic than using *not ever* separately. The reason *not* and *ever* are separated in "Don't you *ever* tell me a lie again" is [*ever*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ever) is used for emphasis as No. 4 definition indicates in the link.

If you contrast "I have never been to the U.S." with "I have not ever been to the U.S.", it would be easier to understand the difference. The latter is rarely (almost never) used.

[*Could*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/could) in the sentence doesn't have any past (tense) aspect. It is used as a modal verb to indicate possibility.